# Reading a text and execute different function, python

Tags: python

i work with python, im making a function that reading a string, execute different function according with the first word of each row, i make something like that but it doesnt do anything:

```
conf_list='''
host / yes / 7200
network / yes / 6000
applications / no / 6500
'''

list_conf={}
k=0
for line in conf_list.splitlines():
    list_conf[k]=line
    #print(list_conf[k])
    if list_conf[0] == 'host':
        print(list_conf[1], list_conf[2]) #output i wanted: yes 7200 
    elif list_conf[0] == 'network':
        print(list_conf[1], list_conf[2]) #output: yes 6000
    elif list_conf[0] == 'applications':
        print(list_conf[1], list_conf[2]) #output: no 6500
```

Maybe these if and elif are not good?

Comment: why is the output for "applications" `yes 6500`?  It's `no 6500` in `conf_list`.

Comment: you are right, my mistake, i change it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you're actually trying to do here. You're creating a dictionary, keyed by an integer which is always 0, replacing the value for that key over and over again with each line, and then accessing that value and comparing it with the strings you're trying to match. That doesn't do anything useful.

I *think* what you want is this:

```
list_confs = {}
for line in conf_list.splitlines():
    thingy, yesno, number = line.split(' / ')
    list_confs[thingy] = (thingy, yesno, number)
```

Now you've got a dictionary mapping each thingy to a set of values. For example, `'host'` maps to the three values `'host', 'yes', '7200'`. So, you can do things like this:

```
list_conf = list_confs['host']
print(list_conf[1], list_conf[2]) # will print yes 7200
```

Answer (score 2):

If `yes` is the name of your function, you can store it in a dictionary:

```
def yes:
    ...
def no:
    ...
functions = {'yes':yes, 'no':no}
```

And execute it:

```
if list_conf[0] == 'host':
    functions[list_conf[1]](list_conf[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conf_list='''host / yes / 7200
network / yes / 6000
applications / no / 6500
'''

def call_host(*args):
    print args

def call_network(*args):
    print args

def call_applications(*args):
    print args

functions = {
    'host': call_host,
    'network': call_network,
    'applications': call_applications,
}

for line in conf_list.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    try:
        # handle arbitrary whitespace
        func_name, truth, value = [ i.strip() for i in line.split('/') ]
        value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        # get here for incorrect number of items or the failure to make the value an int
        print "Malformed line:", line
        continue

    function = functions.get(func_name, None)
    if function is None:
        print "Unknown function:", line
        continue

    function(truth, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, before you try to execute a function, you'd better check whether it's function in your module:

```
import inspect

conf_list='''
    host / yes / 7200
    network / yes / 6000
    applications / no / 6500
'''
adict = {}
for item in conf_list.splitlines():
    if item.strip():
        items = item.split('/')
        tmp_list = []
        tmp_list.extend([items[1].strip(), items[2].strip()])
        adict[items[0].strip()] = tmp_list
for func, args in adict.iteritems():
    isfunc = inspect.isfunction(locals().get(func, None))
    if isfunc:
        locals().get(func)(args)
```